# Used apt-get to install chromium but how to start it?

Tags: icons, shortcuts

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed chromium by using:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Its installed but where does it go? No icon for starting it from desktop.and no icon in Applications-Internet

Please tell me how to run the program and create an icon for it and other applications which I install in future.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 10.04 desktop has reached end of life and is no longer supported. If you are running a still supported version please [edit] your tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can run command `chromium-browser` from terminal. If the symlink was created while installing, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using desktop unity**

The simple way is go to the Dash (the Ubuntu icon at the top of your launcher) and search for "chromium" in the search bar.

[image]

90% of your apps are installed in `/usr/bin` so you can find Chromium there too.